# Jenkins global configuration using REST API

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I need to automate the jenkins installation and plugin configuration in order to configure 'jenkins global settings'. So i tried to configure the same from the remote machine through REST API. but it doesn't work for me.

My efforts:

http://:8080/config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
   <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
   <version>1.653</version>
   <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
   <mode>NORMAL</mode>
   <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
   .................
   .................
```

Answer (score 3):

Default installation of Jenkins provides [remote API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) only for:

- retrieve information from Jenkins for programmatic consumption.
- trigger a new build
- create/copy jobs